# How to refresh SSRS Report inside an ASP .NET Application without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, reporting-services

[image]I have been trying to display SSRS Report in asp .net application. But every time I change he filters and click on 'View Report', the whole page reloads. So I set the SSRS filters as 'Hidden' and created HTML filters, and then on button click, loaded passed the values of hose filters to the 'ReportViewer' manually. But the pae still reloads.

How can I refresh The report without refreshing the whole page?

**Edit :** Wrt to image, the SSRS Report Div should reload and not any other element on the page.

Comment: i don't understand much your question. but what do you mean 'without refreshing the whole page'? so what part do you only expect to change? because through out my experience doing different kinds of report using ssrs in c# the whole page really reloads when the filter is changed. can you add a screenshot to be more clear? thanks

Comment: I am trying to create top filter in ASP.net and the below container with report in SSRS. on change of filter i don't want to hit event post back but  send the filter parameter to RDLC controller and just refresh the report container alone and not the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I've worked with SSRS reports.  You might be able to fudge something together using an iFrame and the query string.

Use your filter to update the URL inside of an iFrame.  If SSRS uses the query string to filter the report this might work.